# Handling registration of multiple participants for an event?

Tags: civievent

I'm not sure if this should be here, in *Mattermost* or in *Issue Reporting*.  It refers to CiviCRM 5.22.0.
We allow on-line registration of multiple participants for an event, and allow a deposit to be paid. The initial registration is *Pending (Pay Later)* as we do not wish to get involved with payment processors and the associated security implications. Instead, we monitor our bank account for such payments. The email sent in response to the receipt of the registration sent to the primary participant contains the information about all the participants. However, the email sent in response to the administrator recording the payment (and changing the status to *Partially Paid* only shows the registration of the primary participant and it also shows the total amount paid and the outstanding balance. Editing and sending another receipt just shows the information about the primary recipient and no balance information.

Would it be better if all such receipts showed:

- The information about *all* the recipients
- The amount paid so far and the outstanding balance.

?

I have been investigating how this might be accomplished and discovered, among other things, that there seem to be several ways in which the total amount payable is calculated, depending on which part of *CiviEvent* is doing the calculation.

Has anyone any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

This by default is not available in CiviCRM ATM. You can alter the message template under System workflow message for 'Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (off-line)' to include additional details. If you are good in smarty variables than you can use api to fetch details like additional participant or payments and include it in your message template, or you can create extension to 
 implement [tokens](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/) and [tokenvalue](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/) hook to add tokens and process the value when rendering message template before it is send to user.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions.  the hooks or smarty variables won't change what is shown against a participant's registration, will they?  My knowledge of smarty is very, very limited.  The question still stands as to whether it would be useful for other people.

Comment: I looked at hooks, but they seemed not to kick in at the right time and had problems returning information to the caller.  Instead, I tweaked .../CRM/Event/Form\EventFees.php, Participant.php and ParticipantView.php and the relevant mail template to display the necessary information.